# how to copy a zip file in one folder to another folder

Tags: java, file-io

I want to copy a zip file from one folder to another folder in java.

i have a migrate.zip file in sourcefolder .i need to copy that migrat.zip file to destination
 folder.

can any one help me on this.

Thanks&Regards,
sivakrishna.m

Comment: use `java.nio.file.Files.copy(...)` for Java 1.7

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946298/best-way-to-copy-a-zip-file-via-java

Answer (score 1):

[**apache-commons-io**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library is helpful in you problem

[org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(File, File)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

```
FileUtils.copyFile(new File("/sourcefolder/migrate.zip"), 
   new File("/destination/migrate.zip"))
```

Comment: -1 `Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);` in Java 7

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below question and answer. This may help you.

[Best Way to copy a Zip File via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946298/best-way-to-copy-a-zip-file-via-java)

Comment: linking or writing a comment in answer is not a proper way to answer.

Comment: Let me correct myself in my upcoming answers. Thank you so much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this set of lines.

```
    String sourceFilePath =" Source path";

    File f = new File(sourceFilePath);
    File f1 = new File(destinationFilePath);
    File fCopy = new File(destinationFilePath);

    if (f1.exists()) {          
        // Don't do anything..
        f1.delete();            
    }
    FileUtils.copyFile(f, fCopy)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use java.util.ZipInputStream class to read migrate.zip file from source folder and use java.util.ZipOutputStream class to write migrate.zip to the destination folder....

```
public class CopyZip
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("source_folder\migrate.zip"));
     ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
     byte[] in_bytes = new bytes[1000];
     zin.read(in_bytes,0,1000);


     FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("dest_folder\migrate.zip"));
     ZipOutputSrream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
     zout.write(in_bytes,0,in_bytes.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: linking or writing a comment in answer is not a proper way to answer.