# Create folder/container with extension but treat it as a file?

Tags: java, file, directory, containers

I have a custom "container" folder. I named it ***.llp***. It is actually a folder which contains inside 2 files that I actually need.

Then I use JFileChooser and tell it to display only ***.llp*** files. But if I select any of those ***.llp*** files/folders it opens them and I see files in it.
I could use workaround:

```
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

But then user can select some different folders as well.

I would be much happier if when I could create that ***.llp*** file/container and that system treat it as a file container, not as a folder. For example, if I double click on it, I don't want it to open but to ask me which program do I want to use to open ***.llp*** file type.

Comment: how about a .zip file or perhaps more appropriately a .jar file?  The filesystem would then see it as a single file, but I seem to recall you could easily open it from Java code and read the contents.

Comment: I also programmatically create those .llp files. Can I create .zip from java and rename it to .llp?

Comment: @vale4674 you can name zip files whatever you want to.

Comment: Check [this post on how to create a zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091788/741249)

Comment: @ Nerdtron I did it with zip file folowing [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CreateZip.html) example. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nedtron didn't put his answer in answer section but in comments I'll answer it.

.zip is the solution.