# Java code to zip file after write file completely

Tags: java

I am writing some code to create a txt file and after completely writing in that txt file, completely close the txt file and then zip that file. But, I don't why, it does not wait until file close before file close it zip it..

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;


public class zipfile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedWriter bfAllBWPownmanmainfest = null;
        String mainfest = "file\\" + "fileforzip" + ".txt";
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mainfest));
        
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksdkhdshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksdkhsdfsdfsddshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksdsdfdskhdshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksddsfdskhdshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksddsfdskhdshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksdsdfdskhdshksd\n");
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.write("jdshsdksddsfsdkhdshksd\n");
        
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.flush();
        bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.close();

        //After close file than zip that!! please help me Thanks
        
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(mainfest);
        zout.putNextEntry(ze);
        zout.closeEntry();
        zout.close();
        
    }

}
```

After close `bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.close();` then zip it, how can I do that. It creates empty zip file, it didn't wait until file close completely!

Comment: Just an fyi, close flushes the buffer so calling flush then close is redundant.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java
You have to write to ZipOutputStream .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a `ZipEntry`, but haven't actually written any bytes to the output zip file. You need to read from an `InputStream` of your file and write to your `ZipOutputStream` after you've `putNextEntry(ZipEntry)`.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mainfest);
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int count;

FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);

ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(mainfest); // this is the name as it will appear if you opened the zip file with WinZip or some other zip manager
zout.putNextEntry(ze);

while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    zout.write(bytes, 0, count);
}

zout.closeEntry();
zout.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your help!! but when you open the zip file it says the file path as well, is there any way that, we can remove that, because when i zip other files in that zip, its doing wrong!! Please help me!!

Comment: thanks for your help!! but when you open the zip file it says the file path as well, is there any way that, we can remove that, because when i zip other files in that zip, its doing wrong!! Please help me!! when i zip other files in it, it create all the folder and than zip file!!

Comment: @user2726811 Change the field you pass to `ZipEntry`. Make it be just the file name (whatever you want).

Answer (score 0):

You don not require `ZipEntry`.Try this code before `bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.close();` satement.

```
    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
    int size = 0;
    byte[] b = new byte[1000];
    while ((size = bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.read(b)) > 0) {
       zout.write(b, 0, size);
    }
    zout.close();
    bfAllBWPownmanmainfest.close();
```