# Method to upload file as zip of S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am using AWS SDK Java for file upload.
I want to upload a file on s3 as zip.

Is there any method which will directly zip my file which I upload on s3.

Or It is mandatory for me to create a zip and then upload to s3.

Thank you.

Comment: Zip the file(s) before you upload them to S3. Or do something complex such as configure a Lambda function to automatically detect uploaded files and convert them to ZIP files (by downloading them, zipping them, uploading them, deleting the original).

Answer (score 2):

You're required to either [zip the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java) before uploading it, or use a [Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/) to zip the file once it's uploaded.

There is no 'helper' in the SDK to achieve what you're asking.