# Create file in zip format

Tags: java, zip, base64

I have a encoded base64 string from a zip file. I try to decode the string and convert to a zip file. I have this code:

```
Path rootDirectory = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/home/myName/driversFolder");
Path tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory(rootDirectory, "");
String dirPath = tempDirectory.toString();
String zipfile = "rbdkjsd4934234234adadds==" //base64 string test
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirPath + "/zipf.zip");
fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(tt));
fos.close();
```

If I go to the folder, I can see a zip file (`zipf.zip`) with the original content and apparently it's a zip .. but it's not. I'm using linux and if i try to `unzip zipf.zip` in command line i have the error:

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is
>   not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. 
>   In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be
>   found on the last disk(s) of this archive.

Apparently it is a zip because file has a .zip name, but is not in zip format. So what is the way to solve this?

Comment: Use ZipOutputStream instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java

Comment: You're not really "converting it to a zip file" - you're saving the data into a file with an extension of `.zip` but that's all. If the data isn't already compressed, you need to be doing the compression part yourself. (e.g. via ZipOutputStream.)

Comment: Can you provide some examples? i try to use zipOutPutStream with my code but i not understand. Thanks for the replys

Comment: Don't you think there might already be some examples online?

Comment: Yes i think but i cannot understand because in the example that i see we use the zipEntry and put singles files (txt for example).. in by case i need to put the base64 decoded because the original zip file have a lot of folders and files....

Comment: What do you get if you run `file zipf.zip`?

Comment: @Meião the shell return: 7-zip archive data

Comment: So it looks like you are putting the correct headers on the file, though the contents aren't correct. You should check ZipOutputStream as mentioned before.