# Spring 4 rest to download URL resource as zip archive

Tags: rest, download, zip, spring-rest, spring-4

I wanted to add a REST service to download a resource found by URL, and archived in ZIP format.

I use the following code to do that:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/downloadAsZip", produces = "application/zip")
@ResponseBody
public Resource downloadSeqRunBinary(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Resource aResource = new UrlResource("/some/path");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="aResource.zip");

    return aResource;
}
```

As a result, I got my zip file, but looks like its broken or doesn't have a proper format, since its unpacked to a .zip.cpgz file.

Could someone point me out what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Is the targeted resource is a valid zip file?

Comment: @MasterPo no, it's just a text file. What I wanted to know is if its possible to make a zip on the fly.

Comment: Please have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java)