# Make Apache Poi Word file downloadable on URL

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

> The ending of poi code:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode("დოკუმენტი-" + loan.getLoanId() + ".zip", "UTF-8"));

File f = new File("autoloanagreement.docx");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

document.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
System.out.println("Success");
```

I have set the controller handler method on `produces = "application/zip"`
and whenever I download the file and try to open it, I get

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged
>
> > EDIT :

I've added new lines of code and now the zip file gets downloaded and opened but I get the new error message of "Unexpected end of zip file"

```
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        DocumentSettingsPart dsp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getDocumentSettingsPart();
        org.docx4j.wml.CTSettings settings = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTSettings();
        BooleanDefaultTrue val = new BooleanDefaultTrue();
        val.setVal(true);

        // Layout Settings
        org.docx4j.wml.CTCompat compat = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTCompat();
        compat.setDoNotExpandShiftReturn(val);
        settings.setCompat(compat);
        dsp.setJaxbElement(settings);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(dsp);

        File f = new File("AutoLoanAgreement");
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(f.getName()));
        wordMLPackage.save(f);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);


        // დავხუროთ სტრიმი
        fileInputStream.close();
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
```

Comment: can you open the file itself without downloading it?

Comment: Just adding `produces = "application/zip"` does not magically create a Zip file. You could use `ZipOutputStream` for example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java

Comment: Yeah I can but in my test project, I copy pasted the code in my real project and mapped the url to it

Comment: Thanks @Jens I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

You send the file as a zip, but never seem to zip the file you are sending. You can wrap the `FileOutputStream` in `ZipOutputStream`, e.g.

```java
OutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Also you never seem to actually pass the file to the OutputStream of the response.

try:

```java
OutputStream os = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
document.write(os);
```

Comment: Thanks @Blokje5 I'll try this as well