# Writing Information (and Image) to a Jar File from another Java Program

Tags: java, executable-jar, overwrite

Possibly a duplicate, though I doubt so since I have not seen anything so far completely answering my criteria in a way that I can complete my program

**Background**

What I need is to access another jar, from a seperate jar, read and write files to that jar. So far what I have done is change the jar to a zip and then I can delete files, but the problem I am having is with writing files back in, specifically image files (.txt works perfectly fine)

**Question**

How do I write image files to a zip (that was originally a jar) from another java program (in the end product another jar)

Note

I have looked around and most sources say this is not possible, but those questions dealt with this during the running of a program, my special case is that the other program is not running, but in file format. All I want to do is write and image in and convert it back to a jar and not have any problems with running that jar in the end.
Thank you!

Comment: you can unzip the files.write them and then zip them back

Comment: @MuhammadAli Would writing the image in and then rezipping it cause any problems? Like is there any formatting issues that could occur? I don't know if java does and compression methods on its image files in the zip or anything like that. Also, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Don’t write to a .jar file used at runtime.  It will have unpredictable results.  If you want to save data, save it to a known location and have your program look in that known location.

Comment: @VGR Nonono, I'm not writing while my jar is running, it is, let's just say program0 writes to program1, program1 is not running right now. It is not concurrent modification.

Comment: That’s good.  But it still sounds pretty unusual.  Why write to a .jar file?  Why not just save each image to a regular file?

Comment: I don't think there should be any issue in zipping files back. Java has a full native library that can zip files in a secure manner.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32962488/7392868

Comment: @VGR I was experimenting with a design that requires that when the new jars are made they are linked to a specific image, and when that jar is run, it runs with the image. I know that this is not the most optimal way, nor a very good way of doing it. This is simple for the idea that it is indeed possible that I'm pursuing the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FileSystems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) to access, write and replace the contents of the jar file:

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("path/file.jar"), null)) {
    Files.copy(Paths.get("path/to/image"), // path to an external image
               fs.getPath("image.jpg"),    // path inside a jar file
               StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: This answer works with any file type in fact. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KrystosTheOverlord I was glad to help!